# how to change div#container height depending the content with jquery

Tags: jquery

In this link i have a map with some dots when i press a dot a text appears besides map, but when the content is bigger (like Ilam dot) the text appears on top of the footer. How could i use jquery to adjust the height depending the dots (city) content.
Thanks!

the link is http://test.dariuscarpets.gr/%CF%80%CE%B5%CF%81%CF%83%CE%B9%CE%BA%CE%AC-%CF%87%CE%B1%CE%BB%CE%B9%CE%AC/

Comment: Post your relevant code here.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can fix this by modify your html structure and css. The fix should like this.

```
<div class="map_container">
    links........
</div>
<div class="detail_container" style="display: block;">
</div>
<div class="city_detail_container">
</div>
```

Change the height of .map_container to 800px.
Remove position: absolute and top: 800px from .detail_container.

Comment: worked great!! 
You are my hero!!